# How to update resolv.conf?

Tags: networking, dns, networkmanager, resolv.conf, resolvconf

I am experiencing DNS resolution issues. I can ping an I.P. on my LAN but when I type it's URL into my browser it does not resolve to the I.P. and I can't access the webpage.

I took a look at the resolv.conf file

```
vi /etc/resolv.conf
```

This shows me two entries:

```
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver IP_ADDRESS_X
```

I logged into my router and found that there are 5 name servers listed:

```
127.0.0.1
8.8.4.4
8.8.8.8
IP_ADDRESS_Y
IP_ADDRESS_Z
```

I can ping Google.com or ping Facebook.com etc... and everything works fine. I assume this is because of the 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 name-servers (i.e. I am able to resolve I.P's outside my local network.)

However, my issue pertains to a VM sitting on some server on my LAN. I can ping this VMs I.P. however I can not access it using it's URL in my browser.

I have also check checked the following files:

```
/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head

    nameserver 8.8.4.4

/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail

    Empty

/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base

    Empty
```

The resolv.conf and resolv.conf.d bot contain comments which state " DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN"

The following describes my attempt at adding the five nameserver addresses found in my router to the resolv.conf file:

```
(1) vi /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base

(2) Added the following I.P's

    127.0.0.1
    8.8.4.4
    8.8.8.8
    IP_ADDRESS_Y
    IP_ADDRESS_Z

(3) Closed the file :wq

(4) Did a resolv.conf update

    resolv.conf -u

(5)  Restarted the network-manager service

    service network-manager restart
```

But when I check /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf all I find is the original two I.P's:

```
 nameserver 8.8.4.4
 nameserver IP_ADDRESS_X
```

How can I update the resolv.conf file such that it will contain the I.P's of all the nameservers which are listed in my router?

Comment: Does the VM's IP get assigned by a DHCP server on your network? If so that's the server where you need to add the extra nameservers you want your clients to pick up in their `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: You can tell NM to add more DNS servers in its configuration.

Comment: @slm Thanks for the info. I'm not sure to be honest, but will investigate this now and see what turns up. I am not convinced this will work though as I have a friend also on the network using a different machine and he can access the URL via his browser no problem.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams Thanks I just looked in the NM script there now. I'm not too sure what I should be editing but will definitely try this out too after I familiarize myself with the file a little more.

Comment: @MarkMark - your friend either added these nameservers locally, or his VM is acquiring them from the DHCP server. That's really the only 2 ways these can get into a system. If you find the dup isn't right for your issue you can edit  your question stating such and it can be reopened.

Comment: What kind of "URL" are you referring to in this context? if you mean things like `myvm.local` then those are typically resolved using local network discovery (Avahi / Bonjour) rather than DNS per se - maybe that's how your friend's machine is doing it?

Comment: @slm Thanks, just to be clear both him and I are not using a VM, we are working off our own independent laptops. We are both trying to access an application hosted on VM on a VM server which is on our LAN. He can open a browser and type app_url and access it no problem but I can not. However we can both ping the VMs I.P.  In any case I think I have found the answer to my question, even though I hae not solved the over all problem. resolv.conf can be updated as follows: echo 'nameserver ip_address' >> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head then do a resolvconf -u

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you, I havn't heard of this before, will investigate. It might make sense in this situation as he can access the VM by entering the following in his browser: /app_name

Comment: @MarkMark - Understood. Yup that's the way to deal w/ it locally, investigating why your laptop isn't picking this up from the DHCP server would be the next thing to dig into. You can look at the log from NetworkManager to see how it's receiving details from the DHCP server. If you don't see all the nameservers listed in its log, you know that your friend did something locally to make tit work for himself as well.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.test & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local

Comment: ... (even simpler) maybe your friend's laptop has an entry mapping the `app_name` server to its LAN IP address in their `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks so much this rectified the issue. I can now access the VM via my browser. I am still concerned as to why I can't do it via the resolvconf but I will investigate this later. Unless anyone ha a problem with the following: I am going to add a solution to this question as echo 'nameserver ip_address' >> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head then do a resolvconf -u because I think this answers the original question I asked. But that for your help

Comment: @steeldriver Just to note I compared contents of the /etc/hosts file on my friends machine versus my machine and oddly he doesn't have the app_name server to the LAN IP address listed. This may indicate the root cause of the problem lies in the direction suggested by @ slm